# Getting a row in the character table using the tensor product example

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

I am calculating the character table of $D_{10}$. I have found 4 conjugacy classes and constructed the trivial representation, the sign representation $\varepsilon : D_{10} \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ and the representation obtained by realizing $D_{10}$ as the symmetries of a pentagon, I have called that representation $\rho$. To be able to write down the character table I need one more representation. I can work this out with column orthogonality, but can it be done with the tensor product? For example, if $\theta$ is a 1D rep of some group $G$ and $\rho$ is any other irreducible rep, then $\theta \otimes\rho$ is an irreducible representation of $G$. So can I use this to write down the last row of my character table without tedious calculation?

Computing the character values of the representation $\varepsilon \otimes \rho$  on each conjugacy class gives me character values identical to $\rho$, so this is wrong. What is going on and what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: There is nothing exactly wrong with your approach, it just didn't happen to work on this example. So the answer to your question is no, you cannot use the tensor product approach to get the last character. There is a group automorphism that maps a reflection $r$ of $D_{10}$ to $r^2$, and you can apply that to your $2$-dimensional character to get the final character.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it now. Conclusion: tensor product need not give a completely new representation of the group, might coincide with an old representation @DerekHolt